# ROR + Disable Browser Cache For Chrome & Safari !

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, safari

I am looking for method to disable `Browser Cache for Chrome & Safari`

I found following method,

```
Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(5));
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);
Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(true);
```

and also for meta tag method.

But i am looking for simple method, to disable browser cache for entire website.

Comment: isn't that simple enough? how simple would you like it to be?

Comment: I need solution, what ever it would be ?

Comment: does the above method not work?

Comment: No. other than chrome and safari, firefox supports

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and found a good solution and I blogged it to

http://www.fordevs.com/2011/10/how-to-prevent-browser-from-caching-a-page-in-rails.html

To add ‘no-cache’, add the following lines @ the application_controller.rb file

```
before_filter :set_no_cache
```

and the function

```
def set_no_cache
   response.headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate"
   response.headers["Pragma"] = "no-cache"
   response.headers["Expires"] = "Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT"
end
```